# Error on localhost after downloading data from Google App Engine to local datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I downloaded all my data from Google Appengine and now see this error on any operations. There appears to be some inconsistency with the app name. How do I change this?

```
BadRequestError: __key__ filter app is s~xxxxxx but query app is dev~xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the app name in the app.yaml so it matches the original app.